# Assigning value in foreach generate

Tags: apache-pig

I'm having trouble with something very simple:

```
data = LOAD a:chararray, b:chararray, c:chararray;
```

Now I want to append a date on (which will either be a constant or a param).

```
add_date = foreach data generate a, b, c, (date = 'today');
```

or

```
add_date = foreach data generate a, b, c, (date = $date);
```

Both of these are throwing me errors in grunt. I know I'm doing something simple wrong, but can't seem to find the answer in the reference manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be just:

```
add_date = foreach data generate a, b, c, 'today' AS date ;
```

No need to put anything in `()`s.